# calculate bounding sphere radius in normalized space

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

I want to calculate the bounding sphere radius in Normalize space that is I want it in the range of 0-1. how can I calculate it? here is my code to calculate bounding sphere radius.I am iterating over the vertices and calling BoundingSphere()

```
void BoundingSphere(const glm::vec3 point) {
    if(min[0] > point[0]) {
        min[0] = point[0];
    }
    if(min[1] > point[1]) {
        min[1] = point[1];
    }
    if(min[2] > point[2]) {
        min[2] = point[2];
    }

    if(max[0] < point[0]) {
        max[0] = point[0];
    }
    if(max[1] < point[1]) {
        max[1] = point[1];
    }
    if(max[2] < point[2]) {
        max[2] = point[2];
    }

    center = (min + max)/2.0f;
    radius = (max - center).length();
}
```

Comment: What is bounding sphere for single point? what is normalized space?

Comment: @MBo I am iterating over the vertices of mesh and calling BoundingSphere(). i want to transform radius into 0-1